# Tensorflow version for CUDA 9.0 and cuDNN 7.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cuda, gpu, cudnn

I would like to know what is the version of **tensorflow_gpu** that I have to install for **CUDA 9.0** and **cuDNN 7.0**?

Best regards!

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Tensorflow 1.0 they started supporting cuDNN 7.0, CUDA version is still 9.0 (as of tf ver 1.12) 
If you are new to Tensorflow, the installation of its requirements is simple but a long process, I usually suggest to my students to install Anaconda (Python 3.6) and then with `conda install tensorflow-gpu` (https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/tensorflow-in-anaconda/) solve their problem, it will install all the requirements. 
Just make sure your python is 3.6